# How can I add sudo permission for copying?

Tags: sudo

my sudoers file:

```
cat /etc/sudoers
...
USERHERE ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/cp /home/USERHERE/foo/in.csv /home/anotheruser/in.csv
...
```

it looks OK too:

```
USERHERE@notebook:~/foo$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for USERHERE on this host:
    env_reset, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User a may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/cp /home/USERHERE/foo/in.csv /home/anotheruser/in.csv
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
USERHERE@notebook:~/foo$
```

but when I try it prompts for password, why?

```
USERHERE@notebook:~$ sudo /bin/cp /home/USERHERE/foo/in.csv /home/anotheruser/in.csv
[sudo] password for USERHERE:
```

Using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Did you use visudo?  the line in my /etc/sudoers reads %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Answer (score 3):

Edit your sudoers file using visudo to look like this.

```
USERHERE ALL= (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/cp /home/USERHERE/foo/in.csv /home/anotheruser/in.csv
```

It will not ask for the password.  If you need more information you can check the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password).

**Testing**

I did the following in my machine. First as root user, issued `visudo` command to edit the `sudoers` file. Then, I added the below entry to permit user *ramesh* to issue network restart command.

```
ramesh ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/network restart
```

After that, I did `su ramesh` to login as that user. Now, I issued the command `/etc/init.d/network restart` and it did not prompt me for password.